# How to detect if a generic lambda is uncompilable in C++ 14?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, sfinae

I have a problem with detecting when an instantiation of a generic lambda is well formed but not compilable, and detecting it has stumped me:

```cpp
#include <functional>

class future
{
public:
  int get() & { return 5; }
};

// Gets the return type of F(A), returning a not_well_formed type if not well formed
template<class F, class A> struct get_return_type
{
  struct not_well_formed {};
  template<class _F, class _A> static not_well_formed test(...);
  template<class _F, class _A> static auto test(_F &&f) noexcept(noexcept(f(std::declval<_A>()))) -> decltype(f(std::declval<_A>()));
  using type = decltype(test<F, A>(std::declval<F>()));
  static constexpr bool is_noexcept = noexcept(test<F, A>(std::declval<F>()));
};

int main(void)
{
  auto foo=[](auto &&x) { return x.get(); };
  using type=get_return_type<decltype(foo), const future>::type;
  return 0;
}
```

This fails with (on clang 3.7):

```
ned@kate:~$ clang++-3.7 -std=c++14 -o weird_generic_lambda_thing weird_generic_lambda_thing.cpp 
weird_generic_lambda_thing.cpp:21:34: error: member function 'get' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const future', but
      function is not marked const
  auto foo=[](auto &&x) { return x.get(); };
                                 ^
weird_generic_lambda_thing.cpp:14:111: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'main()::(anonymous
      class)::operator()<const future>' requested here
  ..._F, class _A> static auto test(_F &&f) noexcept(noexcept(f(std::declval<_A>()))) -> decltype(f(std::declval<_A>()));
                                                                                                  ^
weird_generic_lambda_thing.cpp:15:25: note: while substituting explicitly-specified template arguments into function
      template 'test'
  using type = decltype(test<F, A>(std::declval<F>()));
                        ^
weird_generic_lambda_thing.cpp:22:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'get_return_type<(lambda at
      weird_generic_lambda_thing.cpp:21:12), const future>' requested here
  using type=get_return_type<decltype(foo), const future>::type;
             ^
weird_generic_lambda_thing.cpp:6:7: note: 'get' declared here
  int get() & { return 5; }
      ^
1 error generated.
```

You can probably blame my inexperience with Expression SFINAE here (thanks Visual Studio!), but I am surprised: surely the decltype creating the return type of test() should fail to substitute if `f(std::declval<_A>())` is not well formed?

Obviously the answer is that is does fail to substitute, but in a non-SFINAE way. Can the above be fixed so it correctly returns a not_well_formed type if the generic lambda is uncompilable with some arbitrary parameter type?

Comment: your lambda would need to be declared as `auto foo = [](auto &&x) -> decltype(x.get()) { return x.get(); };` to make it SFINAEable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot in general.  Only early failures can be detected via SFINAE.  Early failures are basically the declaration, not the definition, of a function (or class) template.

The lambda can provide SFINAE early failure instrumentation via explicitly declaring the return type `->decltype(x.get())`, or through other SFINAE techniques like `enable_if_t` or `void_t`.

The idea is that compilers are not required to fully compile functions in order to engage in overload resolution.

Comment: Well, you learn something new then. Thanks for the quick answer.